# Listing files of a given folder in JSON

Tags: vim

Using Vim.
Let's say I have a folder with a lot of files and I need them listed in some way...

choere_01.mp3
choere_02.mp3
choere_03.mp3
choere_04.mp3
choere_05.mp3
choere_06.mp3
choere_07.mp3
choere_08.mp3
choere_09.mp3
choere_10.mp3
choere_11.mp3
choere_12.mp3
...

What would be the most convenient way to generate a JSON file like:

```
 {
   "audio":[
     {"file":"choere_01.mp3"},
     {"file":"choere_02.mp3"},
     {"file":"choere_03.mp3"},
     {"file":"choere_04.mp3"},
     {"file":"choere_05.mp3"},
     {"file":"choere_06.mp3"},
     {"file":"choere_07.mp3"},
     {"file":"choere_08.mp3"},
     {"file":"choere_09.mp3"},
     {"file":"choere_10.mp3"},
     {"file":"choere_11.mp3"},
     {"file":"choere_12.mp3"},
     ...
    ]
  }
```

I have been using Vim for 8 months now and consider myself a newbie.
This task is quickly done in other editors. What is the magical vim-way? Any help appreciated!

Comment: > This task is quickly done in other editors. ->Sorry, if this is off-topic, but this made me really curious, can you please share some examples?

Comment: Well I could have used ls | awk in the first place. In Sublime Text / Textmate etc. I would have ls-ed the files and then do a little copy & paste. So in vim I was probably looking for `:norm` (which I did not know) and somehow did not think of using shell commands straight away. Your answer was eye-opening and a bit embarrassing. ^^} Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if listing the files is the requirement or generating the whole `json`. If it's the latter, Christian's answer is perfect and should work out well for you!

If it's generally listing the files in the current buffer, then there's a more intuitive way to do this. And as you're relatively new, adding this in case you didn't knew this one before (as this really blew my mind, when I came to know of this first time :))

Vim can run external shell commands and enter the output of the command into the current buffer using the `:r!`. This is very powerful as you can pipe multiple commands to get the desired output. For example, you can read a large file using `cat` filter it's output using `grep` reverse `sort` it so on and so forth *and then* enter it to the current buffer.

Anyways, for your example, to enter `"file": "somefile.mp3""` for every file in a directory, you could use the following command:

```
:r! ls /some/directory/where/files/are | grep '.mp3' | awk '{$line = "\"file\": \"" $1 "\""; print $line }'
```

Breaking it down, the command does 3 steps

- listing the files using `ls`
- filtering only the `.mp3` files using grep
- Printing in the required format uisng `awk`

Comment: you could use `:r! ls /dir/*.mp3`

Comment: Oh my god :r! I should definitely sharpen my search skills! Thanks a lot.  :r! ls /path/to/dir | awk '/mp3/ {print "\"file\":\""$1"\","}' does the trick and is very handy!

Answer (score 2):

Well, not sure why you want to do it in Vim, there are probably better tools out there to do it.

However, here is a way to do script it in Vim, It can probably also be done more 
interactively using macros and `:s` magic ;)

First define a Vim Function:

```
func DirContents2Json()
  let list=glob('*.mp3', 0, 1)
  let b=map(sort(copy(list)), { i, v -> {'file': v}})
  return json_encode({'audio': b})
endfunc
```

This function first returns the list of all mp3 files in the current directory and then converts the returned list into a list of dictionaries using a lambda expression. And finally it returns a dictionary with the 'audio' key that contains the list and converts it to json using the `json_encode()` function.

To run it, open Vim in the directory with your files, and then call `:call append('$', DirContents2Json())`. To format it properly, you could then use e.g. `!!python -m json.tool` or something similar.

This needs at least a Vim 8.1